# How to change background color of selected row using Lightning Web Component?

Tags: ecmascript-6, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I want to change the Background color of selected row by clicking the button.
[Output That I Got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czZmA.png)

Comment: Can you show us some code? We are not magicians to guess how your code is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code we don't know how you built this, but in general the way I'd do this is add a css class with the background color you want dynamically when it meets the criteria for coloring (ie onclick, onhover, whatever) and remove it when it doesn't.